# My page styling disappeared after .htaccess was applied

Tags: php, .htaccess

Good day, I'm through with a project , I'm trying to rewrite the urls(static and dynamic)
I tried

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^home index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact contact-us.php  [L]
RewriteRule ^blog blog.php [L]
```

They all worked well.
Until i tried the same thing on dynamic url
Which looks like this.

```
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+) single-mp3.php?uid=$1 [L]
```

After trying the above, it worked but my styling dissapeared.
I also tried.

```
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z]+/([0-9]+)/?$ single-mp3.php?uid=$1 [L]
```

Yet it didn't solve my problem
Please help me out

Comment: what's the url for your stylesheet? - is it under "category/"?

Comment: Category is the custom name i wish to give the new url      , my stylesheet is in a folder called css ...so it looks like this css/bootstrap.css

Comment: @tosinrapsin What's the complete URL of your css file?

Comment: <link href="css/bootstrap.css">

Comment: @tosinrapsin Full URL?

Answer (score 0):

Think this is what you're after:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^home index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact contact-us.php  [L]
RewriteRule ^blog blog.php [L]
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ single-mp3.php?uid=$1 [L]
```

Results in:

```
curl 'http://localhost/home?query='
=> index
curl 'http://localhost/contact?query='
=> contact
curl 'http://localhost/blog?query='
=> blog
curl 'http://localhost/category/someid'
=> Array
(
    [uid] => someid
)
curl 'http://localhost/css/bootstrap.css'
=> css
```